# Conditional distribution with Jeffreys’ Prior

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, jeffreys-prior

If $\pi(\mu,\sigma)$ corresponds to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)\times\mu^{-1/2}$, what is $\pi(\mu|\sigma)$?

Comment: This is the conditional prior density of $\mu$ given $\sigma$.

Comment: unclear: what do you mean by $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$? A Normal density in $\mu$ with mean zero? The $\mu^{-1/2}$ is also unclear as this is only defined for $\mu>0$. Are $\mu$ and $\sigma$ the standard notations for mean and variance?